# Parallel.ForEach nothing or very little is happening

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to read a excel document and write it out as an csv.

I've figured out how to do this in several slightly different ways but it is slow as hell.

this is what I have that is working and is running through 2 arks with each 16384 rows and 5 columns of data in about 1 min 36 seconds

```
  public void ToCSV(Stream excelStream, int i)
    {
        // IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;

        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(excelStream))
        {
            System.Data.DataSet excelsheets = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            foreach (DataTable aSheet in excelsheets.Tables)
            {
                string strCSVData = "";
                string sheetName = aSheet.TableName;

                foreach (DataRow row in aSheet.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var column in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        strCSVData += column.ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",";
                    }
                    strCSVData += "\n";
                }
                string strOutputFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + sheetName + i.ToString() + ".csv";
                StreamWriter csvFile = new StreamWriter(strOutputFileName, false);
                csvFile.Write(strCSVData);
                csvFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to speed it up. I was slightly faster using a normal for loop but nothing spectacular at about 1 min 33 seconds.

So I thought how about using the Parallel.foreach instead. however this resulted in either only a third of the data being written, or none currently.

this is how I changed the above method.

```
 public void ToCSVParallel(Stream excelStream, int i)
    {
        // IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;

        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(excelStream))
        {
            System.Data.DataSet excelsheets = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            for (int sheet = 0; sheet < excelsheets.Tables.Count; sheet++)
            {
                DataTable aSheet = excelsheets.Tables[sheet];
                List<string> strCSVData = new List<string>();
                string sheetName = aSheet.TableName;
                IEnumerable<DataRow> dataSheet = aSheet.AsEnumerable();
                Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>(dataSheet, row =>
                {
                    string strRow = "";
                    for (int column = 0; column < row.ItemArray.Count(); column++)
                    {
                        strRow = row[column].ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",";
                    }
                    strRow += "\n";
                    strCSVData.Append(strRow);
                });

                string strOutputFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + sheetName + i.ToString() + ".csv";
                //StreamWriter csvFile = new StreamWriter(strOutputFileName, false);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(strOutputFileName, strCSVData);
              //  csvFile.Write(strCSVData);
                //csvFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have no idea what I'm doing wrong But I'm fairly sure I must be misunderstanding how I could use the parallel.foreach but what am I doing wrong ?

or is there a better/smarter/simpler way to speed up my method ?

**EDIT:**

Based on all of your suggestions I've come up with the following changes.

```
public void ToCSVParallel(Stream excelStream, int i)
    {
        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(excelStream))
        {
            System.Data.DataSet excelsheets = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            for (int sheet = 0; sheet < excelsheets.Tables.Count; sheet++)
            {
                DataTable aSheet = excelsheets.Tables[sheet];
                ConcurrentBag<string> strCSVData = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
                string sheetName = aSheet.TableName;
                IEnumerable<DataRow> dataSheet = aSheet.AsEnumerable();
                Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>(dataSheet, row =>
                {
                    StringBuilder strRow = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int column = 0; column < row.ItemArray.Count(); column++)
                    {
                        strRow.Append(row[column].ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",");
                    }
                    strCSVData.Add(strRow.ToString());
                });

                string strOutputFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + sheetName + i.ToString() + ".csv";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(strOutputFileName, strCSVData);
            }
        }
    }
```

However based on @Magnus suggestion I also changed my original method to this:

```
public void ToCSV(Stream excelStream, int i)
    {
        using (var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(excelStream))
        {
            System.Data.DataSet excelsheets = excelReader.AsDataSet();
            foreach (DataTable aSheet in excelsheets.Tables)
            {
                string sheetName = aSheet.TableName;
                string strOutputFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + sheetName + i.ToString() + ".csv";

                using (StreamWriter csvFile = new StreamWriter(strOutputFileName, false))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in aSheet.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (var column in row.ItemArray)
                        {
                            csvFile.Write(column.ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",");
                        }
                        csvFile.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the result is astonishing to me.

the parallel is on average 1000 milliseconds slower than the modified Foreach loops.

however my idea to make the method faster is now within acceptable levels. 
the parallel takes on average about 8800 milliseconds.
the foreach loop takes on average 7600 milliseconds. 
both of those is on 2 arks with each 16384 rows and 5 columns of data

Comment: Looking at that I'm nervous about the strCSVData.Append in the loop. I don't think that's a thread-safe structure, nor do I think it makes sense to use one here. Maybe return the values you've added instead, and then combine the ParallelLoopResults? Though I guess what you really want it one List per thread, add to that list and then just combine them afterwards.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to use Excel's functionality to export as CSV?

Comment: Since you are using an async operation,  it might be possible that many writes happening simultaneously and during the write process , the sheet is locked and missing some of the write calls.The best thing would be to query using excel driver and dump all the rows using that query.

Comment: Note that Parallel.ForEach can start tasks in an arbitrary order. Also note, that the order which the tasks finishes is also arbitrary (it is not necessarily in the order in which the tasks were started) Your code as it is now adds data to strCSVData in the order in which the tasks finish. But you rather should add the strRow data to strCSVData in the order of the respective Excel datarows. Also, it might happen that two tasks at the same time append to strCSVData, essentially corrupting the data appended...

Comment: For the sake of clarity, how long does it take to read the excel document without trying to run `Replace` or write it to a CSV? I'm thinking that the optimizations can be divided before we attack the problem.

Comment: In your "normal" loop write to the `StreamWriter` directly instead of concatenating to `strCSVData`.

Comment: If you copied/pasted your code, there is an error there : `strRow = row[column].ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",";`. Did you mean `strRow += ...` ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a list in a multiple thread, because it's not thread safe, instead you should use [ConcurretBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, List doesn't have an Append, it has an Add. Is that an extension?

Comment: At least you could speed up your first implementation by using StringBuilder instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I'm today going to go through each one of your recommendations to see how I fit this in to my code. Will make an update later based on this work and address individual comments over that time.

Comment: you are right that my list is not threadsafe :/ a big oversight on my part. @Rup

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was told to avoid excel's functionality as we cannot ensure that the machine recieving the excel file have the program excel on it. and as I understood using excel's functionality is kinda dependant on having excel installed ?

Comment: @elgonzo you are right I should had used a thread safe collection. 
And I don't care about order just that each line represent a line from the excel document.

Comment: the time to read the excel document is in my case irrelevant as I will be limited by the transfer rate of the internet the document will enter my program memory directly from a https post. and I'm fairly sure the time it takes to read it is less relevant there than the time it takes to write it out from the memory to the csv file

Comment: @magnus love your idea as I have written in your answer.

Comment: @Magnetron yes you are right it is a big blunder on my part I'm working on changing that part now.

Comment: @Cid I will be looking in to that now thank you for spotting that error.

Comment: @Reniuz yes I should probably had used the StringBuilder, but is it faster than writing directly to the file ?

Comment: @Helbo StringBuilder stores everything in memory and it is faster than concatenating strings, but at the end you will write everything from memory to file. So in your case best solution would be to write to file instead of storing to StringBuilder and then writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues with you code.

1. `strCSVData.Append(strRow)` doesn't actually add anything to the list, it returns a new enumerable with the item appended.
2. If you actually did do `Add` that wouldnt work either since List is not thread safe.
3. Doing parallel wouldn't process the items in order. (necessarily)

I think the main issue with your original (non parallel loop) is building the `strCSVData` by concatenating. Since strings are immutable a new string would have to be created every time, and the larger it gets the slower it becomes. I would suggest that you open the `StreamWriter` before the loop and write directly to that one instead.

```
...
StreamWriter csvFile = new StreamWriter(strOutputFileName, false);
for (int sheet = 0; sheet < excelsheets.Tables.Count; sheet++)
{
...
  foreach (DataRow row in aSheet.Rows)
  {
      foreach (var column in row.ItemArray)
      {
           csvFile.WriteLine(column.ToString().Replace(",", "&comma;") + ",");
      }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: that is an interesting approach I will definitely try that then.

you say my list is not thread safe. what would you suggest instead of list ? 
Could I use the same approach of writing directly ? or would I risk each line writing to the same line at the same time ?

Comment: The change you suggested to the original method have changed the time to run by an impressing amount. now we are counting milliseconds instead of minutes. almost thinking that I don't need to do a parallel. However I don't care about the order of each row only about all the data matching each row is related by row. and if I could gain even a little bit of performance then I do believe a parallel would be faster.

Comment: I'm going to add your answer as the accepted one by the end of today unless someone comes up with a revolutionising faster approach then yours is the best answer.

Comment: Doing something in parallel is not always faster as it usually adds complexity for handling the synchronization.